# Add a Record To Last Of The Table

Tags: sql, sql-insert

When I use below query to add new record to the table (at unknown), the new records added to first of table .
I want to add new records to the last of  table .

this my code :

```
begin
insert   into  TBLCrowler (Url,Title,ParentId,HasData) values (@Url,@Title,@ParentId,@HasData) 
end
```

Comment: There is no such thing as the "first" or "last" row in a relational database table.

Answer (score 1):

```
select top 1 CatId, Title, ParentId, Url, CrawlerCheck from TBLCrowler where CatId=(Select min(CatId) from TBLCrowler where CrawlerCheck=1)
update TBLCrowler set CrawlerCheck=2 , HasData=2
where CatId=(Select min(CatId) from TBLCrowler where CrawlerCheck=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, once more into the breach.
You are using a relational database. It's not a worksheet, it's not a rectangular array of cells in a word document. It's power is reliant on being able to store and retrieve records in the most efficient way possible.

Ordering is either implied through an index, which the DBMS is free to ignore, and which could change anyway, or explicitly required through an order by statement

If you want things ordered by the time they were added to the table, you add a created_at column and populate it at the time you perform the insert.

Then when you select from it you add `Order By Created_At` to your select statement.

If you want that ordering to be "fast" you add an index on the Created_At column, which then DBMS will make a brave attempt at using the index in order to avoid the cost of a full pass sort.

Step back and think for a minute about how you would write a DBMS. What would the cost of your implicit orderedness be. Any change to any but the "last" record in the "last" table would mean rewriting to disk every record in every table "after" it. Insert is worse, Delete is as bad and that's without considering that different records take up different amounts of space.

So throw first and last in the bin, if you can find them...

Comment: i find a way here is what i do

Comment: I'm all ears mate, agog in fact. So how are you going to do it?